# Counting all $9 \times 8$ matrices with two restrictions (checking if I'm right)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

I stumbled upon this problem today and I'm not 100% confident my approach is correct. The problem states:

*Count all $9 \times 8$ matrices that fulfill all three restrictions:*

*1) Every element in the matrix is either a 1 or a 0*

*2) Each Row and each Column of the matrix has at most one $1$*

*3) The system of linear equations associated to the matrix has at most 3 free variables*

This was my approach:

First, I interpreted the last condition by saying that $rank(A) = Nº$ of variables $- Nº$ of free variables. So I'm counting matrices that have rank 5, 6, 7 or 8 (max 8 because a 9x8 matrix is associated to a system of 8 variables)

So I added disjoint cases: For a matrix of rank 8, I chose one row that would be empty (all zeroes): ${9 \choose 1}$. Now I have 8 ones to put in 8 rows and 8 columns. I can just line them up like an 8x8 identity and find the permutations I can get by moving the columns around: $8!$. So there's a total of $9!$ matrices of rank 8

For a matrix of rank 7, I now choose 2 rows and 1 column that must be empty, and then permute the non-empty columns. I get ${9 \choose 2}{8 \choose 1}7! = 4 \times 9!$

For rank 6 I do the same thinking process to get ${9 \choose 3}{8 \choose 2}6!$

And for rank 5 I get ${9 \choose 4}{8 \choose 3}5!$

So the total amount of matrices that fulfill all thre requirements is $5 \times 9! + {9 \choose 3}{8 \choose 2}6! + {9 \choose 4}{8 \choose 3}5! $

Is this correct? Is there another more "amusing" approach one could take?

Comment: Yes but there has to be at least 5 ones to fulfill the third requirement

Comment: I changed my mind. Since you have already handled the rank, your solution looks fine to me. :)

Comment: Great! Do you think of other ways this could be done? I'm really curious to see if there's other ways to do this, because usually adding up disjoint cases can be a little tedious

Comment: I don't have another approach for the problem at the moment, but your approach seems to be the most natural one to me and I personally like a solution the most when it's simple and natural. :)